# How to set correct text to textView (I am set RTL in Direction of textView)

Tags: java, android, textview, attr, right-to-left

I want set text compine of English and Persian . But shown text is incorrect

instance :  " cpu چیست؟ "

I am set Direction attr in TextView and set gravity to right!!!

How can give correct text  instance this : " چیست؟ Cpu "

This problem occur time of first term to be English.

Main code of Layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1_define"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

SubCode of ListView :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1_title_define"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="cpu چیست؟ "
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please mention the xml code of Textview that you define in TextView

Comment: If your device is lower than 4.2, `android:textDirection` may not work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add U+202b (RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING) in the beginning of the string, this works for me even in browser:

```html
&#x202b;cpu چیست؟
```

Comment: Also, you can use &#x200e; to force LTR the keyword event it is RTL